# Drupal node migration (migrate_d2d) with revisions

Tags: migrations

I want migrate a Drupal 5 nodes for Drupal 7, use [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) and [Drupal-to-Drupal data migration](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) modules with MigrateDestinationNodeRevision, but migrating only last node revision.

How can I migrate all node revisions?

My test code:

```
<?php

class FoobarNodeMigration extends DrupalNode5Migration {

  /**
   * constructor
   */
  public function __construct(array $arguments) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNodeRevision($arguments['destination_type']);
    $this->addFieldMapping('nid', 'nid')
      ->description('Reuse the old NIDs');
    $this->addFieldMapping('vid', 'vid')
      ->description('Reuse the old VIDs');
    $this->removeFieldMapping('is_new');
    $this->addFieldMapping('is_new')
      ->defaultvalue(TRUE);
    $this->addFieldMapping('revision')
      ->defaultValue(TRUE);
  }
}
```

Comment: *"is not working"* Is pretty useless statement. What actually happens? White Screen of Death? Error message? Nothing bad but no nodes migrated? And most important - you stated a fact. Where is your question?

Comment: Rightful, I edited this post.

Comment: Related issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/1834016